# session, DB or cookie in eCommerce site

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce, state-management

I am creating my 1st `eCommerce` website. After searching a lot i am confused about whether to use `session`, `DB` or `cookie`.

- Some says `session` is best because not every user purchases what he have in cart, `DB` will be very heavy.
- Some says that `DB` should be used so that cart data will persist in different `sessions`.

What is the best choice? What most sites do?

Note: user must login to buy something.

**Edit:** what about that, when a user add something in the cart i insert that in DB TempTable which have a foreign key of userID(user must login to buy something). When users checkouts records from that table will be deleted and inserted into a perminent table.

- If a user left the pc for few hours, he have to login and all data will be there(session problem solved).
- If he uses another pc, he have to login and all data will be there(Cookie problem solved).
- If he removed the cookies, Data still there(Cookie problem solved).

Is this a good technique?

Comment: As you already stated, you must face some trade-offs. I would go to DB, then having a daily routine which clean all older unused sessions, then rebuilding the table indexes

Answer (score 3):

Personally I wouldn't rely on sessions to hold a basket. Customers can quite often spend time on a site, then wander away - perhaps from their desk. should this happen, and they have left their browser and the session expires, then so does their cart...

There are plenty of other reasons too. Maybe they started shopping, closed the browser, went back another time and again would have to start shopping.

What I have a tendency to do is store their cart in a database and the ID to that cart in their cookie. When the user comes back, read the cookie and get their cart. they can continue onwards then. Clear this cookie when the cart has been purchased, so you don't allow them to edit a purchased cart.

I'm sure this has it's downsides too - cookies disabled etc - though I personally try and cater more for the masses, rather than the very rare..

Just my take...

Comment: +1 @syedmohsin There are a lot of different ways the skin the shopping cart cat; this way is probably the best & most scalable.